What is equivalent of this Indexing policy in new Azure.Cosmos client?
I am trying to update the existing DocumentClient to new CosmosClient in Azure and facing this indexing policy object which I am not sure how to upgrade. I know that DocumentCollection is equivalent to ContainerProperties in new cosmos client. The new client has Indexing policy as well but not the same constructor. Does anyone know what will be the equivalent of this DoucmentCollection object in new Azure.Cosmos client:
var collectionInfo = new DocumentCollection
{  
 Id = this.SourceMapping.ResourceDescription.Name,
 IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new 
 RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 })                     
};


That feature is deprecated. You used to be able to set the type and precision, but for quite a long time now it'll default to full precision for all data types. Therefore it was also removed in the new SDK. You'll only have to worry about the paths and mode in the new IndexingPolicy and that only applies when creating or updating a container. The equivalent of your code are the default settings without the need to specify an IndexingPolicy.
